# Restrict JQuery Event to div

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.6

I am trying to restrict the event to just the "manage" div. When I try open the other divs and close them its triggering all the events on the page. I don't want to use specific ID's for each div and would like it just to control whats in one.

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dalond/9Lo0rukh/

and here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.grey_button.close').live('click', function() {
        $('.grey_button.open').click();
        $('.job_description').hide();
        $(this).siblings('.job_description').show();
        $(this).toggleClass('close open');
        return false;
    });
    $('.grey_button.open').live('click', function() {
        $('.job_description').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('close open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: One suggestion  Use `.on`, `.live` has been removed from the latest version of jquery.

Comment: just use `$('.manage .grey_button.open')`  or `$('.manage .job_description')`

Comment: @Mritunjay in the fiddle jquery 1.6 is used :(

Comment: I am using an older version and have restrictions. That's why I am using .live.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am not saying it's an error, I just mentioned as suggetion, I'll update a bit.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oo3u8y7k/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oo3u8y7k/2/

Comment: Thanks Arun - jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oo3u8y7k/2 solved how I would like it to function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery < 1.7

You can specify the event handler to apply to `.grey_button` elements within the `.manage` div in your selector:

```
$('.manage .grey_button').live('click', function() {
    $(this).prev('.job_description').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('close open');
    return false;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/9Lo0rukh/3/)

*Note:* handlers combined, using `.toggle()` on `.job_description` as mentioned below.

## jQuery > 1.7

You can [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) the click event to `.grey_button` elements within the `.manage` div. This is the "modern" approach anyway, [as `live` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc).

You can also replace the two event handlers with one, and use `.toggle()` to define the open/close for the description.

```
$('.manage').on('click', '.grey_button', function() {
    $(this).prev('.job_description').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('close open');
    return false;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/9Lo0rukh/4/)